# Convert decibels to amplitude - Built-in function

Tags: units, education

Is there a built-in function to convert decibels to amplitude in *Mathematica*? I tried with:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[40, "decibels"], "amplitude"]
```

but it does not work.

Online I found only a widget for Wolfram Alpha:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=21e1ea77bd91aaa0fc4d01a943a654e

[image]

Comment: `10^(amplitudeIndB/20.)`

Comment: Hello @andre, I am looking for a built-in function that does the same thing.

Comment: Definition of decibel varies from one area to another: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Definition I guess this is the reason why _Mathematica_ refuses to convert it.

Comment: Why insist on built-in?  I think answer will be no such built-in, although the external resources (databases, W|A) continue to evolve, I think.  W|A does not seem currently to be able to recognize "amplitude ratio" or the ISO term "root-power quantity," which does not seem to be an ISO unit per se or have a unit name/symbol.

Comment: Hello @MichaelE2 I would like to learn all possible ways to get the same result; for this reason I was looking for a built-in function. Thank you for the question.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The confusing part is, the document of `Quantity` claims that "Supported units include all those specified by NIST Special Publication 811. " And decibel is indeed [mentioned there](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication811e2008.pdf)…

Comment: @xzczd But I think decibels are known. It is the root power ratio that is unknown, which the OP calls `"amplitude"`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Interestingly, decibels and bels are both unknown, `Quantity[1, "decibels"]` returns `Quantity[1, IndependentUnit["decibels"]]` and `Quantity[1, "bels"]` returns `Quantity[1, IndependentUnit["bels"]]` 囧

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I knew. I thought you would point out that `UnitConvert` cannot convert decibels to bels, though. It says they are incompatible (`Quantity::compat`), which seems an error to me.  It seems an `IndependentUnit[]` is treated as having "no relationship to other units within a Quantity."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing in the documentation, and bellow you can see what you can find in the internal functions, of which nothing that seems to do the job. So the answer to your question is:

***No, there is no built-in function to convert decibels to amplitude in Mathematica***.

---

### Speculation on *"why"*

We can only guess why the developers didn't implement this, a possible narrative may be similar to the case of the now deprecated `Units` Package. There the [documentation said](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Units/tutorial/Units.html):

> "The conversion of temperature units is different from most other unit
>   conversions because it is not multiplicative. This is simply because
>   the zeros of various systems are set at different values. For example,
>   zero degrees Centigrade is the same as 32 degrees Fahrenheit."

So you had to use `ConvertTemperature` instead of `Convert`.  How is that similar? It's similar because both cases are somehow special.  [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel)

> The decibel (symbol: dB) is a unit of measurement used to express the
>   ratio of one value of a physical property to another on a logarithmic
>   scale.

dB is NOT an amount of a physical quantity, but a the logarithm of a ratio of two quantities in the same units, therefore unitless and non-linear. Also depending if the you are talking about amplitudes or power (amplitude squared) the factors are 20 or 10.

Therefore, non-linear relationship of something that arguably may not be even a unit with a potentially ambiguous definition... better leave it to the users to define their own, rather simple, solutions.

---

### A solution

```
dB2lin[x_] := N[Power[10, x/20]];
lin2dB[x_] := N[20 Log10[x]];
```

---

### Internal functions

Some functions with matching names

```
Names["*`*Decibel*", IgnoreCase -> True]
(* {"Signal`Utils`decibelQ", "Signal`Utils`decibelQ$", \
"CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`DecibelsMuUnit", \
"CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`\
DecibelsMuUnit", "CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`DecibelsRUnit", \
"CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`DecibelsVUnit", \
"CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`DecibelsZUnit"} *)

Names["*`db*"]
(* {"Image`ColorOperationsDump`db", \
"Image`ColorOperationsDump`Image`ColorOperationsDump`db", \
"Predictions`Private`db", \
"Predictions`Private`Predictions`Private`db", \
"Statistics`Library`Dump`dbag", "Statistics`Library`Dump`dbag$", \
"PacletManager`LayoutDocsCollection`Private`dbFile", \
"System`FourierTransformDump`dbgPrintFT", \
"Charting`ChartLabelingDump`dbgstyle", \
"Charting`ChartLabelingDump`dbgstyle$", \
"Charting`ChartLabelingDump`dbox", "Charting`dbPrint", \
"Image`ColorOperationsDump`dbPrint", "Image`HumanDump`dbPrint", \
"Image`SpatialOperationsDump`dbPrint", \
"Visualization`VectorFields`VectorFieldsDump`dbPrint", \
"Wavelets`WaveletUtilities`dbPrint", \
"PacletManager`LayoutDocsCollection`Private`dbStrm", \
"PacletManager`LayoutDocsCollection`Private`dbStrm$", \
"Charting`CommonDump`dbstyle", \
"Charting`ChartLabelingDump`dbTimingReap", \
"Charting`ChartLabelingDump`dbVpp", "Charting`ParserDump`dbVpp", \
"System`ListPointPlot3DDump`dbVpp", \
"System`ListPointPlot3DDump`System`ListPointPlot3DDump`dbVpp"} *)
```

Comment: Hello @rhermans, thank you for your extremely clear answer.

Comment: "It's not an amount of a physical quantity, but a the logarithm of a ratio of two quantities in the same units, therefore unitless. " Hmm… but `UnitConvert[Quantity[40, "AngularDegrees"], "Radians"]` works.

Comment: @xzczd remember that with the `Units` package *"The conversion of temperature units is different from most other unit conversions because it is not multiplicative. This is simply because the zeros of various systems are set at different values. For example, zero degrees Centigrade is the same as 32 degrees Fahrenheit."* so you had to use `ConvertTemperature` instead of `Convert`. Is not that there are no ways around, but these are special cases. And radians is closer to the idea of a units, as they are amounts of $\pi$

Comment: Well, `"AngularDegrees"` isn't a unit for temperature, it's a unit for angle, which [is dimensionless](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803955/58219). With this example I just want to illustrate that dimensionless or unitless doesn't seem to be a reason for the "failure" of _Mathematica_.

Comment: @xzczd Sure, I guess it's all speculation to guess why the developer's didn't implement anything. My point was that *dB* not been a real unit, **added to the nonlinearity** (log) and the ambiguity of power and amplitude makes it a special case. Not a justification, just a narrative that attempts to explain the special circumstances. Do you think I should delete that part out? BTW, I haven't confused angles and temperatures, two parallel examples.

Comment: I think it's better to note in the body of answer that it's mainly a guess :) .

Comment: `UnitConvert` will call ``Internal`MWACompute["MWAToQuantity", name]`` to use WolframAlpha to assist with units when the unit `name` is not among the built-in ones.  Now W|A can convert between decibels and bels, but `UnitConvert` cannot.  So the call to W|A might only result in an `IndependentUnit[]` that cannot be converted.